# Facebook Messenger Chat Plugin not Firing messaging_referrals event in Webhook Request

Tags: facebook, webhooks, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to integrate messenger on my website. I want to track users (by Cookie Value). There is a option in Facebook Chat Plugin, "[messaging_referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_referrals)" which tells referral key of user chatting.

As per instructions i have added event "messaging_referrals" in facebook app webhook events.

But still in my webhook i'm not getting referral key.

My Plugin Code looks like this

```
<div class="fb-customerchat"
 page_id="ABC"
 ref="OPTIONAL_WEBHOOK_PARAM"
 logged_in_greeting="<GREETING_MESSAGE_FOR_LOGGED_IN_USERS>"
 logged_out_greeting="<GREETING_MESSAGE_FOR_LOGGED_OUT_USERS>">
</div>

<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId            : 'XYZ',
  autoLogAppEvents : true,
  xfbml            : true,
  version          : 'v2.11'
});
};
(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And Request I'm getting in my webhook is this

```
"data": {
        "sender": {
            "id": "abc"
        },
        "recipient": {
            "id": "ABC"
        },
        "message": {
            "mid": "mid.$cAADv109V6n_F6BY",
            "text": "hi",
            "seq": 511,
            "tags": {
                "source": "customer_chat_plugin"
            }
        },
        "timestamp": 1522049646776
    }
```

As per [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_referrals#customer-chat) i should also be receiving "OPTIONAL_WEBHOOK_PARAM" in my webhook request

Comment: Found a solution?

Comment: Did you find a workaround/solve this?

Comment: @AdamMarshall nopes, i couldn't, so i left the facebook messenger and developed my own

Comment: Graph API v3.3: Still no `referral.ref` field in the webhook response as per the official [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_referrals#customer-chat). Replied "No" to the "Is this page helpful?" survey on the bottom left of the doc page, checked "Accuracy" and described the lack of support/docs for ref.

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how the `ref` field work in facebook.

### MAKE SURE YOU HAVE REMAINED YOUR CHAT CONVERSATION HISTORY

THEN YOU FOLLOW THIS INSTRUCTION.

1. You must logout the current facebook , if you have.
2. you open your chat messenger within your website , THEN by click  `Login into Messenger` button  , will pop the Facebook login form for you, so just fill it and login.
3. After step 2, you will see in your website messenger box appear with button `Continue as YOUR_FB_NAME` Then you click this button, then the `ref` field will trigger .

Here is my log for proof as answer ( I am using SDK version 7.0) .
[image]

In your HTML customer chat might be look like this

```
<!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
     attribution=setup_tool
     page_id="11xx695540xxxx"
     ref="your-ref-pass-to-webhoooks"
     theme_color="#DA615C"
     referer_uri="your-website-uri"
     logged_in_greeting="Question-1"
     logged_out_greeting="Question-2">
</div>
```